# cgal + array of points

Tags: arrays, point, cgal

I know that in CGAL we can have access to elements of Point_2 in the following way:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point_2;
Point_2 points(1.0,1.0);

int main(){
std::cout<<points.x()<<"\t"<<points.y();
return 0;}
```

but how can I do this for an array of points:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef std::vector<Point_2> Vector;

Vector points;
points.reserve(N);

int main(){
points[0].x() =1;
points[0].y() =1;
return 0;}
```

points[i].x() or points[i].x produces error.

Comment: What is `Vector`? Why are you calling `reserve`? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: `reserve` doesn't do what you think it does, please read its doc. Assuming you have done `resize` instead, you can do `points[0]=Point_2(1.0,1.0);`. If you stick to `reserve`, that would be `points.push_back(Point_2(1.0,1.0));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the friend mentioned in the commentary, you can do:

```
    int main(){

        points.push_back(Point_2(1.0,1.0));
        return 0;

    }
```